# I can't chose false option for radio type

Tags: symfony4

I have a flag field (as boolean) in my entity. In my form, I would like radio buttons. Display is fine but when I chose false option, I have an issue like if I chose nothing. **How can I fix that ?**

***Entity.php***

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 */
private $isPublic;
```

***FormType.php***

```
        ->add('isPublic', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' => ['private' => false, 'public' => true],
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => false,
            'label_attr'=>[
                'class'=>'radio-inline'
            ]
        ])
```

***_form.html.twig***

```
    {{ form_widget(form.isPublic) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.isPublic) }}
    {{ form_help(form.isPublic) }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`false` is not really a printable value.

You have to use some stringified values like `"0"` and `"1"` and use a data transformer to convert them to a boolean representation.